# How to copy a file or jar file that has built from jenkins to a diff host server

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

Am having a jenkins job where am building a jar file. after the build is done I need to copy that jar file to a different server and deploy it there.

Am trying this yml file to achieve the same but it is looking for the file in the different server other than the jenkins server.

```
---
# ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{inventory_dir}}/private_key"
 - hosts: host
   remote_user: xuser
   tasks:
    - service: name=nginx state=started
      become: yes
      become_method: sudo
   tasks:
    - name: test a shell script
      command: sh /home/user/test.sh
   tasks:
    - name: copy files
      synchronize:
           src: /var/jenkins_home/hadoop_id_rsa
           dest: /home/user/
```

could you please suggest is there any other way or what could be approach to copy a build file to the server using jenkins to deploy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per my knowledge you can use Publish Over ssh plugin in jenkins. actually i am not clear about your problem. but hoping that this can help you. plugin details: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin if it wont help you, please comment. can you please more specific. (screen shot if possible)

Comment: we are currently using jenkins blue ocean am unable to see where we can setup use ssh during a build.
Is there any clear documentation on that.
Am new to jenkins.

Comment: In build section itself. After your build step complete, you can transfer the file from your  job workspace to the destination server. All you need to do is configure the remote ssh connection as he mentioned in the above link

Answer (score 0):

Use remote ssh script in the build step no plug in is required

scp –P 22 Desktop/url.txt user@192.168.1.50:~/Desktop/url.txt

Setup passwords less authentication use the below link for help

https://www.howtogeek.com/66776/how-to-remotely-copy-files-over-ssh-without-entering-your-password/